# Laravel Query Sending Different Result For Same Problem

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi I am trying to create a one on one messaging system on LARAVEL. It was working all fine until for some users it started showing different result then expected. And it happens only for some users.. What is wrong with this query

```
$id =$receiver->id;
$messages = Message::where(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
              ->where('receiver_id', '=', $id);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                ->where('receiver_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        })->get();
```

After I return $messages the result is like this...

**Working Result**: Messages are coming sequentially..

[image: Working Result]

**In View It shows like this.**.

[image]

**Same Query Bad Result**

[image]

**In the view you can see date are not aligned in order**

[image]

I really can't figure out what went wrong if you can help I would really appreciate..

Comment: what issue .? you are gettiing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is casting as UTC with ISO-8601 format, but I think date is not related with your issue, if you are not ordering with timestamp. 
I suggest you to use `orderBy` with `id`, it can solve your issue easily :

```
$messages = Message::where(function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
              ->where('receiver_id', '=', $id);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $id)
                ->where('receiver_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really did not think about ordering as it was giving correct result from the beginning.. As I populate messages from top to bottom instead of DESC I used ASC and it worked. Thank you for your help. If you can edit and make ASC i would mark it correct.

Comment: Opps, sorry. I edited DESC as ASC. Nice to hear that it helped